# TensorBoard doesn't find scalar statistics

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Has anyone gotten TensorBoard working? Doesn't seem to find my ScalarSummary files.
I'm using:

```
$ python /Users/nikhilbuduma/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/tensorboard/tensorboard.py --logdir=~/Documents/tensorflow_playground/feedforward_mnist/data
```

and: `~/Documents/tensorflow_playground/feedforward_mnist/data` contains a file called `events.out.tfevents.1447172341.31-34-222.wireless.csail.mit.edu`

Which I assume are the scalar summaries?

Comment: how did you get tensorboard to run?

Comment: So I just found the tensorboard.py file that was installed in my virtual env (located in `/Users/nikhilbuduma/tensorflow`), and ran that. The exact shell command is in my post, but is in the form:

`$ python TENSORBOARD_PATH --logdir=DATA_PATH`

Comment: havent tried the virtual env installation. will try when i get back from groceries ;)

Comment: is there a pip install for tensorboard? i might be blind.

Comment: @darksigma: There's no pip install for TensorBoard - it comes with TensorFlow. Also, try clicking on the "graph" tag - if you see a visualization of the MNIST graph, that indicates TensorBoard is loading the data properly, and you just haven't written scalar summary data out.

Comment: I don't see a graph visualization unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to call tensorboard with an absolute logdir path.
For me it helped at least to see the graph. Unfortunately summaries still are not shown.